# Programatically logging in as admin user on Drupal 8, using Cypress

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, cypress

Trying to test some content creation test using cypress on Drupal 8 site, however having trouble logging in programatically as recommended on Cypress's doc
(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app.html#Logging-in)

Followed the steps on this site (https://sevaa.com/blog/2018/10/end-to-end-testing-with-drupal-and-cypress/), but when I ran cy.login(username, pwd)(I'm using actual value, not undefined variable...), always get 403 forbidden error.

Also, while I'm able to login using UI and I can navigate admin section of Drupal by clicking on links, but soon as I use cy.visit('/admin/content') I get 403 error...

Has anyone successfully bypass this 403 errors by logging in programatically?
And if so, how did you manage to do so?

Comment: Have you set the baseUrl to the url used by your site? The blogpost you link to mention the baseUrl quite early but very briefly, so you might have overlooked changing it to the Url you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend installing [Cypress-drupal](https://github.com/epicflux/cypress-drupal) node package. After that you can login with simple `cy.drupalLogin('admin', 'admin')` command.